# How to Null check multiple columns, with casting reporting elements

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, data-quality

Looking for the most efficient way to check for nulls and have a desired output for a report. This is done in a Hadoop environment.

For example,
Database contains:

| FirstName | LastName | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | {null} | OH |
| Jane | Smith | {null} |
| Pikachu | Pokemon | HI |

The output from the query would be:

| RuleNum | ColName | DefectCount | TableCount | DateofData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rule001 | FirstName | 0 | 50 | 2023-01-01 |
| Rule002 | LastName | 1 | 50 | 2023-01-01 |
| Rule003 | State | 1 | 50 | 2023-01-01 |

The embarassingly clunky and inefficient query that that I use, which works- but it takes a LONG time to get results is(and we check thousands of columns)- and i'm unsure as to how to get the table count included efficiently:

```
SELECT
CAST('Rule001' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RuleNum,
CAST('FirstName' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS ColName,
A.DefectCount AS DefectCount,
CAST(('date_add(current_date(),-1)) AS VARCHAR(255) AS DateofData
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DefectCount
FROM DbName.TableName
WHERE FirstName IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
CAST('Rule002' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RuleNum,
CAST('LastName' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS ColName,
A.DefectCount AS DefectCount,
CAST(('date_add(current_date(),-1)) AS VARCHAR(255) AS DateofData
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DefectCount
FROM DbName.TableName
WHERE LastName IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
CAST('Rule003' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS RuleNum,
CAST('State' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS ColName,
A.DefectCount AS DefectCount,
CAST(('date_add(current_date(),-1)) AS VARCHAR(255) AS DateofData
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS DefectCount
FROM DbName.TableName
WHERE State IS NULL
```

Comment: I've removed the conflictin (R)DBMS tags. You will need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the product you are *actually* using.

Comment: for the output you wanr there isn't a better way, but why not have all columns defined as NIOT NULL, so that you don't need to count

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was SQL Server until `CAST(('date_add(current_date(),-1)) AS VARCHAR(255) AS DateofData`.  So not so sure anymore.

Comment: I would build a dynamic query to get a row of  null counts for nullable columns of the table and unpivot it.

Comment: The date field isn't as important- the syntax can be adjusted... or even put in at a later time in Excel or another BI tool that we're researching(Alteryx). @Serg any tips or resources as to where I may find such a dynamic query, please? Thanks!

Comment: Creating a dynamic query varies by product. What is your DBMS exactly?

Comment: @Serg Hadoop. our database admins mentioned to me that Hadoop does not use a RDBMS system- everything is a backend with distributed files, and the front end is Hive. Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: Hive does use a RDBMS for the metastore